# Why does password_verify work on old passwords generated with crypt and a random salt?

Tags: php, php-password-hash

I understand that `password_hash` returns the salt and hashing algorithm as part of the result, and so I get why `password_verify` works and will be backwards compatible with hashes generated by `password_hash`.

However, I have a database of older hashes from a PHP 5.4 environment, which used crypt and a randomly generated salt. To my surprise, `password_verify` returns expected values of true and false for these too. I see crypt also prepends info about the salt and algorithm to the result string, but `password_get_info` doesn't seem to parse it.

```
php > echo crypt('test1','salt');
saTBKtwSCLJ0A
php > echo crypt('test1','sa_anything');
saTBKtwSCLJ0A
php > echo crypt('test1','newsalt');
ne0fA1VwB4hx2
php > echo crypt('test3','$6$salt');
$6$salt$NGtBMjsb3SEYv95mjN8yKuZMkYSjFJQDt8yu8JMnXJLv/NWugOVDTnqPeBqp94mf6T20sHoY.wSNWwtTSPvqM0
php > var_dump(password_get_info('$6$salt$NGtBMjsb3SEYv95mjN8yKuZMkYSjFJQDt8yu8JMnXJLv/NWugOVDTnqPeBqp94mf6T20sHoY.wSNWwtTSPvqM0'));
array(3) {
  ["algo"]=>
  int(0)
  ["algoName"]=>
  string(7) "unknown"
  ["options"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

One of the user notes in `verify_password`'s documentation states

> This function can be used to verify hashes created with other functions like crypt().

but doesn't say why.

I'm wondering what's going on in the background, and whether `password_verify` is *guaranteed* to work on crypt-generated passwords or if I should still be checking for them.

Comment: **password_hash() is a simple crypt() wrapper and compatible with existing password hashes** http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

Answer (score 3):

The "hash" actually contains the hashing mechanism and the salt at the beginning of the string.

In your example, `$6$` stands for SHA-512, you can try `man crypt` for a few more IDs.

It's easy for the function to get the correct algorithm and check the actual password against its hash.

Comment: More importantly, if it begins with 2 letters, it means it's the old `crypt()` algorithm.

Comment: It looked like that was what was happening, but I'm wondering why password_get_info doesn't return algoName => "sha-512"?

Comment: @Simone because password_get_info is documented to work when its input is "a hash created by password_hash".